# How to get count from mapping table group be another table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have three tables:

```
store 
=====
   name
   address 
   city 
   state 
   country 
   tag ..., 

post
=======
    title
    summary 
    tags ...

store_post_map
================
(mapping on store and post based on tag).
```

Now I want to get count of posts from mapping table group by `city`, `state`, `country` or `store.id`, what to be the SQL in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Please clarify your schema with actual column names and declare your foreign keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, it's this:

```
SELECT store_id, count(*) AS posts_ct
FROM   store_post_map
GROUP  BY store_id;
```

> How can we get counts for each city, state or country where each area
>   can have multiple stores?

Count per country:

```
SELECT s.country, count(*) AS posts_ct
FROM   store          s
JOIN   store_post_map sp ON sp.store_id = s.id
GROUP  BY 1; -- positional parameter - is the same as GROUP BY s.country here
```

For the count per `city` you may have to `GROUP BY` `area` and `country` in addition since a city name is hardly unique. Like:

```
SELECT s.city, s.area, s.country, count(*) AS posts_ct
FROM   store          s
JOIN   store_post_map sp ON sp.store_id = s.id
GROUP  BY 1, 2, 3;
```

Comment: Thanks Erwin,
we get counts for each store this way as we have store_id in map table, how we can get counts for each city, state or country where each area can have multiple stores?

Comment: can we get other column form store table, like store.name of store having max count?

Comment: Yes you can. Add it to the `SELECT` list *and* the `GROUP BY` list. Then you get counts per store, obviously.

Comment: Thanks Erwin, so now I think I need separate query to get extra fields if I want to group by city, country etc and get extra details based on max count, isn't it?

Comment: @bhupesh: Sounds like it. There are many ways to do that. the best one depends on your circumstances. Start a *new question* if you need advice with it, and don't forget to mention your version of Postgres.